# Why isn't an IIFE used for privacy when implementing Events?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In [backbone](http://backbonejs.org/), when storing events, this convention is used to denote a private variable:

```
_events
```

However, as we know, this property is very much not private.   Why not do something like this to make it really private?

```
var Events = (function () {
    var publik = {},
        events = {},      // private object literal
        eventsApi,        // private method
        triggerEvents;    // private method

    // define publik Events methods here

    return publik;
})();

_.extend(Backbone, Events);
```

Comment: Encapsulation in these specific cases really isn't the huge deal people make it out to be. We're all consenting adults. Just because the library lets you change stuff you know you're not supposed to, doesn't mean you should.

Comment: I don't plan on changing it - never said I did.  I'm asking why not actually make it private.  It also adds encapsulation ( the visual type ) instead of having two "floating" function definitions.

Comment: I'm not blaming you of anything, don't worry :) I'm just saying making it private isn't really a big deal. The "_" convention means "It's there, if you're absolutely sure you know what you're doing use it, but you're not supposed to"

Comment: I don't know where the angst came from in the comments that were here, but I trust it won't happen again, from any party involved.

Answer (score 6):

Otherwise, it's rather a matter of convention.

The convention is that people don't make it hard. Use a simple function, no IIFE, and let people mess with your "private" variables if they desperately need to.

Did you ever have to change a library's code because this library hid its variables? Well, it's a real pain when it happens. Having the variables available, even though they're "private by convention", is a real benefit.

For the reference, [Common Lisp][0] has all its variables private by default. You can manually export some. But you can always reach even the private variables with a special syntax, making it clear that the code is doing something it shouldn't (messing with "undefined behavior").

[0]: Arguably [the most powerful language](http://www.paulgraham.com/avg.html), but clearly one Javascript is based on.

Comment: I don't know where the angst came from in the comments that were here, but I trust it won't happen again, from any party involved. Also, the image that was originally on this answer was... not appropriate.